Share variables between two python scripts, one Flask script(Script 1) and a second script which waits for data from script 1
i am trying to set up a system where a Flask script recieves data from Postman, stores them in a dict and passes them to a second python script which then uses these variables to execute some task. My code looks something like this:
#Script 1(flask-script):#
#this script recieves request and stores in a dict to pass on to script 2#
#Initialize the Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "super secret key"

@app.route('/save_frame', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def save_frame():
    #recieve request arg from postman#
    jobnummer = request.args.get('JOB')
    date= request.args.get('DATE')
    #save to dict#
    res = {"jobnummer" : jobnummer,
           "Date" :  date}
    
    return jsonify(res) , 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False,port=5000, threaded=True, host= '0.0.0.0')

#Script 2(camera is running and checks if Script 1 has sent data then saves that frame)#:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

while(True):
# Capture frame-by-frame
ret, frame = cap.read()

# Display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

### 
if data from script one is recieved:
first print the data then 
save the frame 
else keep the camera running
###

if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

#When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

So is there any way to exexute the part of second script
### 
if data from script one is recieved:
first print the data then 
save the frame 
else keep the camera running
###

Any suggestions would be very welcome :)
